# Generar código de React respetando espacios o saltos de linea

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

cuando creo una aplicación de React el código se crea en una sola línea y elimina espacios, esto hace que por ejemplo los btn de bootstrap se "peguen"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
```

si los divs estan separados por un espacio o un salto de linea se mostraran separados de lo contrario estarán pegados
[image]

Lo solucione colocando etiquetas  `&nbsp;`,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Si mejoras un poco más la pregunta puedo entender de manera más específica lo que buscas si mi respuesta no te fue util de lo contrario espero haberte ayudado, saludos!

Comment: Es de mala educación editar la pregunta. No permitas que editen tu pregunta

Comment: Si quieres poner un espacio como muestras.el.primer span, solo agrega esta etiqueta HTML `&nbsp;`, esto te agregara un.pequeño espacio entre los dos span

Answer (score 1):

Es fácil, tu problema no es con react sino con tu componente, debes entender que estas utilizando el elemento span que es un elemento de tipo en línea quiere decir que los botones debes darle o un estilo con css:

algo asi:

```
span{
   display: block;
}
```

o al lado de cada etiqueta span puedes agregar una etiqueta de salto de línea:

```
<span>soy un boton</span><br>
```

Comment: con display: block; para el span hace que ocupe todo al ancho del contenedor y el salto de linea no me sirve por que quiero que estén juntos pero con un pequeño espacio pero si en el código html los tags no están separados con un espacio de esta forma "<span>1<span/>espacio<span>2<span/>" se pegan, en los componentes de react si lo estan pero al renderizarse de pierde ese espacio o salto de linea entre tags